# react-native deeply nested overlay

Tags: reactjs, react-native

TLDR;

**What's the best approach to create an overlay that covers the entire screen, from somewhere deep inside of the component hierarchy?**

There's a lib that's called `react-native-overlay`, which seems to be abandoned. It also feels like this should be solvable with the core RN features.

---

Just to provide some background; basically, the thought is to mimic an in app, item-menu like the one Facebook has, see image below. Basically, each item should have it's own menu button. When tapping the menu button, a menu appears. Tapping outside of the menu should close the menu.

Now;

1. AFAIK, there's no window which you can add a tap-handler for detecting when a click is done outside of the menu area. Therefore, my thought was to create an overlay that covers the entire screen, to be able to capture the taps.
2. What's the best way to create such an overlay? `position: 'absolute'` is only relative to the parent component since each component, unless specified explicitly, has `position: 'relative'`.

One option would be to add an onLayout handler, and then set the top/left to negative values to compensate for the offset of the component, but that feels hackish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-root-modal?

It's similar to react-native-overlay but implemented with pure JavaScript